# How to display app name inside Google Cast app's chromecast card

Tags: android, google-cast

I'm going through Google Cast's test cases here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/testing and in row 121 it requires `The app name under content title is visible and correct`

My app failed to display the app name and I couldn't find related doc, please help. It does display media title and media description/subtitle well

I'm using castv2 sdk (actually the cast companion library) in sender app and the receiver app is using styled media receiver. The receiver app is published and I'm able to cast media to the receiver app by using my sender app.

I tried a few other apps such as youtube and twitch and all of them display their app name in the chromecast card. I just don't know where to look at? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The app name that should show up in the card should come from the name you gave your receiver in the developer console when you registered your Styled Receiver. I suggest you try CastVideos-android-v2 (which is CCL based) to validate that.